# Writing contents of gensim Doc2Vec to Azure blob

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script which will have effectively no local file storage access.  It is currently a Jupyter notebook, but needs to become an Azure Databrick later on.  It will, however, have access to Azure blob storage.

We are currently writing the output using this type of process:

```
doc2vec_results = Doc2Vec( <parameters and values> )
doc2vec_results.build_vocab(data)
<processing and stuff>
doc2vec_results.save(file_location)
```

That works, but without local storage that process no longer works.  So, instead, it would be very convenient to save what would have been the contents of that file to a variable, like `doc2vec_result_savedata` and then write that to a blob:

```
new_blob_name = f"doc2vec_data_{timestamp}"
blob_url = f"{account_url}/{container_name}/{new_blob_name}"
blob = BlobClient.from_blob_url(
    blob_url=blob_url,
    credential=credential
)
blob.upload_blob(doc2vec_result_savedata)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this result?  The methods in the Doc2Vec class don't present an applicable option.  I'm also considering making a file object (something from the io module, perhaps?), writing to that, reading it to a variable, etc... but that really seems excessive.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use an `io.BytesIO`:

```py
from io import BytesIO

fh = BytesIO()

# this takes a string or a handle
doc2vec_results.save(fh)

# save using the handle
blob_client.upload_blob(fh, blob_type="BlockBlob")
```

Comment: Nice!  So I guess that was the way to go.  It's working well.  Thank you.